# PIL Сравнения изображений

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow, pil

Написал функцию которая возвращает True или False в зависимости от того является ли изображение идентичным. Я прогоняю эту функцию в цикле и меня не устраивает время отработки. Как мы видим нам нужно открывать постоянно картинку. Что бы постоянно этого не делать я открываю картинку за функцией, но другие картинки приходится открывать. Как можно сократить время? Может можно как-то добавить в бд хеши? Важно что бы был именно PIL так как мне важна точность результата, остальные методы сравнивания показали себя плохо. (pixelperfect сравнение)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
img = Image.open(img)
def isSignature(img, tpl):
    original = img
    template = Image.open(tpl)
    result = ImageChops.difference(original, template).getbbox()
    if result == None:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Можно ускорить для отрицательных результатов, сравнивая изображения попиксельно, и возвращать false при первом расхождении

Comment: @ganz вполне логично, но не думаю  что если я буду писать эту логику на python это будет отрабатывать быстрее чем PIL.

Comment: Так же можно ускорить отрицательный результат, если размер файлов не совпадает.